# Safety of dual-boot systems

Tags: dual-boot, security

At present I use a Mac Mini for online banking, shopping, etc. but a Windows 8.1 PC for everything else.

If I install Ubuntu on a separate partition of the PC, and use the BIOS boot option menu at startup to select which operating system to use, can I be confident that malware infiltrating the Windows system cannot jeopardise the financial transactions I do when booted into Ubuntu?

My concern is not for damage to files or data on the Ubuntu disc/partition (which I could replace), but the security of my financial dealings whilst logged on to banks, Amazon, Tesco, etc via my Ubuntu internet browser.

Given that nothing is certain in life, would I be safer (rather than 'safe') if I continued to use the Mac for this financial work, instead of running Ubuntu on the PC?

Comment: Are you trying to ask if your Windows malware will execute in an Ubuntu environment? (answer: No) Or are you asking if unwise browsing habits are have less consequence in Ubuntu? (answer: No) Or are you asking if an Ubuntu-based browser will read your Windows profile, and import unwise extensions that have been installed? (answer: Maybe) Or are you asking something else? Your question is not clear.

Comment: A separate Linux partition on a Windows machine will be as safe as your completely independent Mac PC. You can even access all of your files from the Windows partition without any worry of Windows malware affecting your Ubuntu installation. You may even find that, after awhile of using Ubuntu, you may never need to boot into Windows again.

Comment: Usually the person using the computer is best security/risk factor for any OS.  Ubuntu is understood to be safer than Windows, since fewer risks for it.  Browsers can still be attacked in Ubuntu, but usually just need a shutdown to fix or a reinstall.  Probably the safest would be to use a live usb version, but will need to reinstall to update it, since they usually don't retain any changes.

Comment: Reviewers: Please don't close vote this question as a duplicate of any other question before checking to make sure that the other question has better answers than this question. Otherwise the duplication should logically go in the reverse direction.

Answer (score 3):

There are some very good points in the comments. There are many ways the security of your financial dealings can be compromised. I will list a few.

## Some Features of Ubuntu

There are a couple of features of a dual boot system running Ubuntu that are relevant to your question:

### File System

The file system used in a default installation of Ubuntu is not readable from Windows without installing a third party driver. What this means is, the Ubuntu partition is completely unknown to Windows. Windows cannot read anything that is in the Ubuntu partition, and it cannot write to the Ubuntu partition.

This in turn means if your Windows partition is infected by a malware designed to work on Windows it will have no effect on the Ubuntu partition.

### The Executable

Software (and malware) designed to run in Windows do not work in Ubuntu default installation. One can get around this restriction by installing Wine in Ubuntu. However, for your purpose you don't need and should not install Wine.

This means even if you inadvertently download a Windows (or Mac) malware while in Ubuntu, it will not work in Ubuntu. Of course, this is not true if the malware is designed for Linux.

## Some Specific Threats You will be Safe from

This is by no means a complete list. These are just a few I could think of:

### Keylogger

A Windows malware keylogger that records every key you press can capture your online banking user ID and password and send it to the thief. In a dual boot system when you are using Ubuntu, the Windows system is turned off. Therefore such a malware installed in Windows will not present a threat to your online activity in Ubuntu.

### Phishing

If you use the Windows to read your email and Ubuntu for online financial activities, you will be relatively safe from phishing attacks. Phishing is an email based attack where you get an email that looks like it is from your Bank (or Amazon, or Tesco). The phishing email usually contain links that would take you to a fake website where the thief would capture your banking credentials.

However, if you can control the urge to click on the link in the email and boot to Ubuntu to login to your bank's website, you will be safe.

### Rootkits (some)

This is a broad class of malware that can steal passwords. They are hard to detect. Some of these are Windows specific, and may not work when you boot Ubuntu.

### In General

You will be safe from malware that need to install or run something in Windows to work.

## Some Specific Threats to Worry About

These days there are malware that do not need to have a local executable to work. They may work on various servers or divert you to malicious websites. For example:

### Rootkits (some)

There are some Linux specific rootkits. Some rootkits are OS agnostic. Some of these may hide in the UEFI/BIOS. That means they can do their dirty work irrespective of which OS you are using. Booting Ubuntu will not stop these kinds of malware.

### Encryption Malware

Encryption malware that targets Windows files is not a threat to dual boot Ubuntu. Similarly, encryption malware that targets Linux servers may affect Ubuntu desktops as long as the desktop does not run any server daemons.However, some encryption malware infect the internal drives Master Boot Record (MBR) and make the drive unbootable. If such a malware infects your computer when you use Windows, you may not be able to boot either Windows or Ubuntu in a dual boot system until you fix the MBR.

### DNS Hijack (and Other Server Side Threats)

DNS is the server that interprets the web address you type (or use from Bookmarks/Favorites) and sends your browser to the correct web page. A DNS hijack can send you to a malicious web page that looks exactly like your banking page. This kind of threat works at the Internet scale, and does not depend on which operating system you are running.

Running Ubuntu will not save you from such threats.

### Cookies

If you select the option to "keep me logged in all the time" option at a site like Amazon, the information stored by the browser can be read by either some local malware or by some server side malware. Though you will be relatively safe from local malware (particularly, those intended to run in Windows) there is no safety in Ubuntu from any server side threats.

## Good Practice

In general it is a good idea not to save your passwords in the browser or select "stay logged in all the time" option.

### An Alternate to installation

One option for **just for online banking and shopping** is not to Install Ubuntu in a partition. You can use a Live USB/DVD for your financial activities. A Live USB/DVD is the same one you would use to install Ubuntu into your computer. Normally, you would boot from the Live USB/DVD and select "Install Ubuntu" option. However, in this scenario you do not want to install Ubuntu, but use it directly from the Live USB/DVD. For this you will select "Try Ubuntu without Installing" option.

The advantage of the Live USB/DVD is that it is a read only system. That is nothing is saved when you visit your banking and other website. There is a way to get around this limitation by making a Live USB persistent, but you don't want that.

Nothing is saved means it is impossible to have a permanent malware infection in the Live USB/DVD, even one specifically built for Linux. It also means no passwords are saved and you will have to login again when you boot from the Live USB/DVD. That is, "keep me logged in" does not have any effect.

**This option does not negate all the security risks. However, as the Ubuntu live USB/DVD has a read-only file system the security risk surface is smaller.**

Hope this helps

Comment: Would be worth to mention other attack vectors subjects: partition/disk encryption, UEFI/SecureBoot and rootkits.

Comment: Yes I upvoted this answer and now it's time for me to hunt big game because this question has the best answers, so I close voted [Ubuntu installed alongside an infected Windows system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161510/) as a duplicate of this question and I encourage you to do the same. It was posted first does not automatically make it a better question.

Comment: Not sure if the idea of live USB is better for security since both the OS and browser is unpatched with latest releases. This unless the live USB is burned regularly viz very recent rolling release. Also what if the said rootkits infect the live USB itself?

Comment: @ShubhamDeshmukh feel free to provide your own answer. Anything is possible. There is no 100% safe system. This question and answer is not for full time use of Ubuntu. This is for online banking only.